# ruby how read user input in scanf-style like in C++

Tags: c++, ruby, scanf

I am new in Ruby.
I need to read from user input (n) numbers and in C++ i used this code

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
  scanf("%d",&array[i]);
}
```

this code read exactly (n) numbers separated by any white spaces (tabs, spaces, newlines).

How i can do this in ruby?

in Ruby I tried to do it like this

```
require 'scanf'
n = scanf("%d");
arr = Array.new()
n.times { arr << scanf("%d") }
```

but this code don't work when i intut string like this:

```
1   4    8
```

but works fine if i input this

```
1
4
8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have to admit in this instance I'm unable to make a program that is quite as compact as the C++ version. It seems in Ruby `scanf` does not work like the C++ version for `IO` streams, and for strings you will need to provide a block to achieve multiple scans per line.

So here's one solution:

```
a = Array.new
n = gets.to_i

while a.length < n
  gets.scanf("%d") { |d| a << d[0] }
end
```

The only problem you get here is if you request for example 3 numbers, and then the user inputs 10 numbers on one line, then `a` will contain all those 10 numbers. To fix it you can just always truncate the array after the loop is done:

```
a = a.take(n)
```

This solution will read `n` numbers from the input regardless of white space. The user can input them all on one line, or on separate lines, or a mix of both (which I assume was your original requirement).

Answer (score 5):

### Use String#scan

I'm not 100% sure that I know what you really want to do here. If you just want to scan a string for digits, you can use [String#scan](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan) to do something like this:

```
digits = '1   4    8'.scan /\d+/
# => ["1", "4", "8"]
```

This will return an array of digits found in the string, and you can access your *digits* array with any [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html) or [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) method you like.

If you want to handle newlines as well as tabs or spaces, all you need to do is add the `m` flag for multi-line matching. For example:

```
digits = '1
          4 8'.scan /\d+/m
# => ["1", "4", "8"]
```

Comment: I want to read n numbers from user input and put them in to the array.
and not paying attention to what they are separated (any kind of whitespaces)

Comment: @JohnZwinck - Like he said he wants to read N numbers from user input regardless of white space, which can include newlines or not. So the solution has to be generalized for both cases (user inputs numbers with spaces, or with newlines, or a mix of both).